# Backbone Collection Not firing Add Event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So i have a problem whereby I have a backbone collection that am using to create function to save data to a REST API. The data is saved to the server and a model is added to the current collection but then the add event for the collection is not fired.Below are snippets of the code
The views initialize function

```
intialize : function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.updateList);
    },
```

The updateList function only does a console log.The views function that saves data using the collection is:

```
cards = this.collection;
        debugger
        cards.create(data, {
            success : function(model, response) {
                console.log("success on saving card");
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Updating list");
                console.log(cards);
            },
            error : function(model, response) {
                console.log("error on saving card");
                console.log(model);
                console.log("response");
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
        return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your view:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('add', this.updateList, this);
}
```

Or:

```
var someCollection = new SomeCollection();
var view = new SomeView({collection: someCollection});
view.listenTo(someCollection, 'add', view.updateList);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work so i dont know whats the problem. I am using backbone 1.0 which recommends the use of listenTo() instead of on

Comment: Where you see in backbone documentation, what it recommends use ``listenTo()`` instead ``on()``? The documentation say: ``The advantage of using this form, instead of on(), is that listenTo() allows the object to keep track of the events,and they can be removed all at once later on`` - this is different what you have written in previous comment.

Comment: try to add ``console.log('event is fired);`` to your callback function... Please, see my updated code.

Comment: Yea sorry about that its was just a recommendation I have since moved on from the issue which started to work apparently on its own, I have not been able to know what was wrong yet.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use: `this.model.on('change', doAction, this);` inside the view? if I understood correctly, this is a better solution since your model is changing.
plus, I couldn't find anywhere a place where the ListenTo() is mandatory over the On() function, can you tell me where you saw it?